# Allow clicking a link through a div that is bound to the "click" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have a `div` containing some content, in which there are some links. The `div` itself watches for the `click` event so it can make the content editable. However, I want the user to be able to click the links inside of the `div` and have it navigate to the linked page rather than edit the content (clicking anywhere else in the `div` should edit the content though). How do I achieve this?

Code example:

```
<div id="content">
    Here's a <a href="http://google.com">link</a>.
</div>

// jQuery Javascript:
$("#content").click(function() {
    // Make content editable
});
```

(Clicking on the link shouldn't make the content editable, and instead should direct the page to `google.com`.)

Edit: I'm using my own code to make the content editable (switching out the div with a text area, that sort of thing).

Comment: Did you try binding the link a click handler?

Comment: are you using a plugin for the editable content?

Comment: Wow, all the answers seem like they work. Which one is the most elegant?

Comment: Can you please show the content of your div's click handler? Does it call `preventDefault` on the click event? If so, don't call `preventDefault`.
How do you attach your click handler? If you use jQuery for this then please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the question's tags, but I think the selected answer will determine what I do in the `click` handler. I don't call `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the event target and return true

```
$("#content").click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

*Not tested*

The thinking behind this is to bail-out early from the handler and, by returning true, allow the browser to handle the event the usual way.

Comment: So simple - makes mine look like such a mess (it kinda is anyway)

Answer (score 2):

One error you have is that you are using `content` as a class in your HTML, but as an ID in your jQuery. So you should change your HTML to `id="content"` (assuming no other elements on your page already have that id.

Your Javascript can look like:

```
$("#content").click(function(){
    this.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    $(this).focus();
}).blur(function(){
    this.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false'); 
});

$("#content a").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q77Bs/

Comment: It becomes important to block the `editable` behavior when the link is clicked if you're opening the link in a new tab / window. And even if you're not, it's a weird visual effect to have the content become editable and then have the page disappear.

Comment: Also, the JSFiddle isn't working in Safari 5.1 (clicking the link isn't going to the page, just making the content editable).

Comment: @Chetan You're right, it does need to have bubbling up prevented in some browsers. I edited my post. contenteditable is an HTML5 feature. I thought that was what you were using from your OP, but now I understand you are using some other script or plugin. I'm not sure how supported `contenteditable` is yet.

Comment: Upvoted for using HTML5, but unfortunately I don't want to require HTML5 to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/nrDkS/)

use [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
// jQuery Javascript:
$(".content").click(function(e) {
    // make content editable
});

$('.content a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the z-index of the link to be greater than that of the div (not sure if that will work), or you can place each link inside another div with a higher zindex than the main div. This will prevent clicks from registering on the primary div, so make sure the secondary divs are correctly sized so as not to prevent the editing functionality

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content a ').live("click", function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

this will do the trick